# Set same color as prev row if data matches otherwise different color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a requirement in which I need to set color of two or more rows of a table same if they have same value in cell one and I have to maintain this alternatively i.e. no 3 or 4 rows should have the same color unless there cell value is same.

I have written following code but I don't like it that much as it seems dirty.

```js
function SetGroupingDetails(row, item, color, namedColor) {
  $(row)
    .css("background-color", color) //set different color for different groups
    .addClass(namedColor);
}

$("#tblExport tbody tr").each(function() {
  var item = $("td:first", this).text();

  var prev = $(this).prev();

  if (prev.length > 0) {
    var prevItem = prev.find('td:first').text();

    if (prevItem == item) {
      if (prev.hasClass('Green'))
        SetGroupingDetails(this, item, "#009933", "Green");
      else
        SetGroupingDetails(this, item, "#cc9900", "Orange");
    } else {
      if (prev.hasClass('Orange'))
        SetGroupingDetails(this, item, "#009933", "Green");
      else
        SetGroupingDetails(this, item, "#cc9900", "Orange");
    }
  } else
    SetGroupingDetails(this, item, "#009933", "Green");
});
```

```css
#tblExport body {
  font: normal medium/1.4 sans-serif;
}
#tblExport {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
#tblExport th,
td {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#tblExport th {
  background: #bfbfbf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblExport">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Item No.
      </th>
      <th>
        Item Name
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>
        10178601
      </td>
      <td>
        X
      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        10178601
      </td>
      <td>
        X
      </td>

      <tr>
        <td>
          40062595
        </td>
        <td>
          Y
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          40062595
        </td>
        <td>
          Y
        </td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          80214549
        </td>
        <td>
          Z
        </td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          80214549
        </td>
        <td>
          Z
        </td>

      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As previously mentioned, `#tblExport body` should probably be `#tblExport > tbody`, and you should `trim()` text before comparing.

It is possible to reduce the five calls to `SetGroupingDetails()`.  If you don't try to set a `background-color` manually, then it's a simple matter of adding either a "zebra-even" class or a "zebra-odd" class.  Simply toggle between them whenever the text doesn't match its predecessor.

```js
var c = 0;
$("#tblExport tbody tr").each(function() {
    var $item = $("td:first", this);
    var $prev = $(this).prev().find('td:first');

    if ($prev.length && $prev.text().trim() != $item.text().trim()) {
        c = 1 - c;
    }
    $(this).addClass(['zebra-even', 'zebra-odd'][c]);
});
```

```css
#tblExport > tbody {
  font: normal medium/1.4 sans-serif;
}
#tblExport {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
#tblExport th,
td {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#tblExport th {
  background: #bfbfbf;
}
#tblExport > tbody > tr.zebra-even {
  background-color: #093;
}
#tblExport > tbody > tr.zebra-odd {
  background-color: #c90;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblExport">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Item No.
      </th>
      <th>
        Item Name
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>
        10178601
      </td>
      <td>
        X
      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        10178601
      </td>
      <td>
        X
      </td>

      <tr>
        <td>
          40062595
        </td>
        <td>
          Y
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          40062595
        </td>
        <td>
          Y
        </td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          80214549
        </td>
        <td>
          Z
        </td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          80214549
        </td>
        <td>
          Z
        </td>

      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing `$.addClass(namedColor)`, then why are you setting the `background-color` explicitly?  Just define CSS rules for the two classes that will set the background color.  Also, CSS class names should be neutral about the visual effect they produce, so `zebra-even` and `zebra-odd` would be better names than `Green` and `Orange`.

Your `#tblExport body` rule makes no sense.  Did you mean `#tblExport > tbody`?

You should `trim()` the text before comparing.  Otherwise, the whitespace would become significant.

You could reduce some of the redundancy in the calls to `SetGroupingDetails()`.  However, since this task is fundamentally a grouping problem, you should have some kind of `groupBy()` function in your code.  You could write such a function, but it would be smarter to use a library such as [lodash.js](/questions/tagged/lodash.js) or [underscore.js](/questions/tagged/underscore.js).

```js
_($("#tblExport > tbody > tr"))
 .groupBy(function(row) {
    return $(row).find('td:first').text().trim();
  })
 .values()
 .chunk(2)
 .forEach(function(rowGroupPair) {
    $(rowGroupPair[0]).addClass('zebra-even');
    if (rowGroupPair.length > 1) {
        $(rowGroupPair[1]).addClass('zebra-odd');
    }
  });
```

```css
#tblExport > tbody {
  font: normal medium/1.4 sans-serif;
}
#tblExport {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
#tblExport th,
td {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#tblExport th {
  background: #bfbfbf;
}
#tblExport > tbody > tr.zebra-even {
  background-color: #093;
}
#tblExport > tbody > tr.zebra-odd {
  background-color: #c90;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.5.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblExport">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Item No.
      </th>
      <th>
        Item Name
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>
        10178601
      </td>
      <td>
        X
      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        10178601
      </td>
      <td>
        X
      </td>

      <tr>
        <td>
          40062595
        </td>
        <td>
          Y
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          40062595
        </td>
        <td>
          Y
        </td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          80214549
        </td>
        <td>
          Z
        </td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          80214549
        </td>
        <td>
          Z
        </td>

      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks but I would not like to add dependency. Can you suggest something on grouping. I have changed class names to be generic and used them rather than adding color. Just simplification of usage of SetGroupingDetails is where m stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You pass "item" as second parameter to your function ...

```
function SetGroupingDetails(row, item, color, namedColor) {
```

... but within your function-body it isn't used.

```
  $(row)
    .css("background-color", color) //set different color for different groups
    .addClass(namedColor);
}
```

You should get rid of that.

Comment: I forget to remove it. Shrinked the actual function and item was being used in that.

Comment: ;) Cool job your script, nevertheless.